# SELECT INTO command not allowed within multi-statement transaction in Hibernate for Sybase DB

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, sybase, sap-ase

I was new to hibernate and trying to execute an procedure from a Java file using hibernate to a Sybase DB. While i am trying to run the application i am getting an error like below

**Stored procedure 'dbo.p_chklist_test' may be run only in unchained transaction mode. The 'SET CHAINED OFF' command will cause the current session to use unchained transaction mode.**

I have checked in few forums and set the mode as "Any mode" by running below command.
sp_procxmode p_chklist_test, "anymode"

Also i have set the Auto Commit as False in hibernate.

Now i am getting a different error like below

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1191)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:357)
    at com.lcit_release.server.dao.ReleaseItemDao.searchRecordsNew(ReleaseItemDao.java:198)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy8.searchRecordsNew(Unknown Source)
    at com.lcit_release.server.logic.ReleaseItemLogic.searchExisting(ReleaseItemLogic.java:147)
    at com.lcit_release.server.adapter.ReleaseItemLogicAdapter.search(ReleaseItemLogicAdapter.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
    ... 41 more


**Caused by: com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: SELECT INTO command not allowed within multi-statement transaction.**

    at com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.Tds.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.Tds.nextResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.ResultGetter.nextResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.updateLoop(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at msjava.tools.db.jdbc3.MSDBPreparedStatementImpl.executeUpdate(MSDBPreparedStatementImpl.java:315)
    at msjava.tools.db.jdbc3.MSDBPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(MSDBPreparedStatement.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:189)
    ... 62 more
```

I have check few sites for the error **SELECT INTO command not allowed within multi-statement transaction** and set the parameter **"ServerInitiatedTransactions"** as false in the configuration xml

```
**<ConnectProperties>
    <Property name="ServerInitiatedTransactions">false</Property>
</ConnectProperties>**
```

But this even dint resolve the issue and i am getting the same error. Can someone please help me on this.

**My Code:**

```
 String sql3 ="exec dbo.p_chklist_test";
         System.out.println("sql 3 is "+sql3);

            Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql3);


             sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().connection().setAutoCommit(false);



         query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);


         listRelItem = query.list();
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I have run the exec p_chklist_test command form the Sybase DB and it is working fine and i getting the desired result. But while i was trying to get the data from Java i am facing this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check your stored procedure for statements like

SELECT id INTO #a FROM students.

This statement is okay from DB perspective but when executed from a Java Program this won't work and give the above error.

First, define the temporary table

CREATE TABLE #a(
id INT
)

INSERT INTO #a
SELECT id FROM students

The above fix works.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue by calling the procedure in the below manner. Hope it might help others to figure it out.

**SET CHAINED OFF exec p_qa_existing_items**

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is because you should "never" try to use "select into" while a transaction(select @@transaction) is open, call it from any platform Java or any other application.

I believe solution given by @swat is pretty much you should use rather than SET CHAINED OFF. There could be impact due to this as in your code as I understand SET CHAINED was ON for some reason. So there might not be any code in SP when there is need to open a transaction but you have not as SET CHAINED is ON.

You can play with this in Sybase -

create proc testproc
as
select * into #temp from table
return
go

begin tran
exec test_proc
commit tran

begin tran
exec test_proc
rollback tran

(I do not have my Sybase environment with me now so cannot check it for myself. but this could definitely help you understand the cause)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Jboss, and I couldn't change the procedure because it was provided by the client. In my case the problem stopped after configuring the datasource to use

```
jta="false".
```