# 'CREATE INDEX' command is not allowed within a multi-statement transaction in the 'tempdb' database

Tags: hibernate, sybase

I am running a proc from java using hibernate (code below) when I get the below error:

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("<query_name>");
    query.setParameter(0, businessDate);

    return query.list();
```

Error: 
SQL Error: 2762, SQLState: ZZZZZ
The 'CREATE INDEX' command is not allowed within a multi-statement transaction in the 'tempdb' database.

The proc runs fine when I run it from db(sybase). Can someone please let me know how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: did you look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605632/select-into-command-not-allowed-within-multi-statement-transaction-in-hibernate)

Comment: You probably called your SP inside a transaction created by hibernate/spring?